# How to extend the Google android architecture dagger sample?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

[Google Repo Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp). All of the boilerplate code is taken from there.

I just can't figure out how to add my own dependencies to this architecture.
I want to do the following things:

1. I need to use one of the presenters in a non-fragment class.
2. I need to add a network module, which provides a simple OkHttp client.

I understand dagger in general, but dagger-android confuses me in many parts..

**ToDoApplication:**

```
public class ToDoApplication extends DaggerApplication {
    @Inject
    TasksRepository tasksRepository;

    @Inject
    AsyncTask asyncTask;

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

**AppComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TasksRepositoryModule.class,
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<ToDoApplication> {

    TasksRepository getTasksRepository();
    AsyncTask getAsyncTask();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        AppComponent.Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class ApplicationModule {
    //expose Application as an injectable context
    @Binds
    abstract Context bindContext(Application application);
}
```

**ActivityBindingModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = TasksModule.class)
    abstract TasksActivity tasksActivity();

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = AddEditTaskModule.class)
    abstract AddEditTaskActivity addEditTaskActivity();

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = StatisticsModule.class)
    abstract StatisticsActivity statisticsActivity();

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = TaskDetailPresenterModule.class)
    abstract TaskDetailActivity taskDetailActivity();
}
```

---

**ExampleModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class TasksModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract TasksFragment tasksFragment();

    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds abstract TasksContract.Presenter taskPresenter(TasksPresenter presenter);
}
```

**ExampleActivity:**

```
public class TasksActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {
 @Inject
    TasksPresenter mTasksPresenter;
    @Inject
    Lazy<TasksFragment> taskFragmentProvider;

...
```

**Example Fragment:**

```
@ActivityScoped
public class TasksFragment extends DaggerFragment implements TasksContract.View {

    @Inject
    TasksContract.Presenter mPresenter;

...
```

**Example Presenter:**

```
@ActivityScoped
final class TasksPresenter implements TasksContract.Presenter {

    @Inject
    TasksPresenter(TasksRepository tasksRepository) {
        mTasksRepository = tasksRepository;
    }

...
```

---

The code above is all correctly working. Now my problem:

1. I have an `AsyncTask`, which needs a presenter to post something in it's `onPostExecute` method. I injected the presenter, but I get the error that the presenter is not initialized.
2. I added the following `NetworkModule` to the module array in `@Component` and simply injected it in the `AsyncTask`, but it's not working (error: ... not initialized). What else would I have to add?

**NetworkModule:**

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttp(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient()
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

     @Inject 
     TasksPresenter presenter;
     @Inject
     OkHttpClient client;

     protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
         client.doSomething();
         ...
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         ...
         presenter.doSomething();
     }
 }
```

All of my code is correctly working without dagger so you don't have to worry about it. :)

I hope somebody can help me. If you have further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Could you please include how you set up the async task and how/where/when you inject it?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak added the simplified  AsyncTask :)

Comment: And where do you inject the AsyncTask? Adding `@Inject` alone to some properties will not do anything

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Ok that seems to be my problem. I added `@Inject AsyncTask asyncTask;` to the application, `AsyncTask getAsyncTask();` to the component and `@Inject` to the constructor of MyAsyncTask. Now I get the error `A binding with matching key exists in component com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.di.ActivityBindingModule_TasksActivity.TasksActivitySubcomponent`. I understand that this means, that the dependency is in my graph but it cannot be reached. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using constructor injection for the AsyncTask and only passing the Okhttp client in the constructor. I no longer inject the presenter in the AsyncTask, instead I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a) to return a value from the AsyncTask to the presenter.